# My eclipse luna won't start up

Tags: java, eclipse

So this basically this happens either when:
-I install the e(fx)clipse plugin into eclipse and then restart eclipse
-I copy the eclipse folder onto a network and put the folder on another computer to use the eclipse.

Currently I am facing the second one. Can you guys teach me how to read an eclipse log file? Also, please tell me on what I have to do with this.

My remedy is always get the base eclipse luna zip and then plug in for e(fx)clipse. Then hope that on my next start up it won't die on me.

LOG FILE

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.runtime"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.0.v20140318-2214"; singleton:="true" [id=51] STARTED!SESSION 2014-09-01 11:27:12.399 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_20
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2014-09-01 11:28:13.706
!MESSAGE [SCR - WorkThread] Timeout occurred! Thread was blocked on processing [QueuedJob] WorkPerformer: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager@ccdee4; actionType 1

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2014-09-01 11:28:14.096
!MESSAGE [SCR] Enabling components of bundle org.eclipse.ui.trace did not complete in 30000 ms 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.ide.java6 4 0 2014-09-01 11:28:14.221
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.fx.ide.java6 [296]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version>=1.3)(!(version>=1.8)))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2014-09-01 11:28:19.274
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0 [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Answer (score 27):

I had a similar problem with an unexpected reboot while eclipse was running.  I could not start eclipse.   Checked the .log file and had the same lock error message.  I removed the .lock file from my workspace.metadata folder and was able to start up again.

Comment: I had similar issue on Liferay Developer Studio and this worked for me like a charm ! Thank you.

Comment: Time saver solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me. If you go to your workspace directory perform the following steps:

1. cd .metadata/.plugins
2. mv org.eclipse.core.resources org.eclipse.core.resources.bak
3. Start eclipse. (It should show an error message or an empty workspace because no project is found.)
4. Close all open editors tabs.
5. Exit eclipse.
6. rm -rf org.eclipse.core.resources (Delete the newly created directory.)
7. mv org.eclipse.core.resources.bak/ org.eclipse.core.resources (Restore the original directory.)
8. Start eclipse and start working.

Solution, coutersy of the following:
http://off-topic.biz/en/eclipse-hangs-at-startup-showing-only-the-splash-screen/

Comment: I needed to delete the .snap File in the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/ dir see @Gert 's answer

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly the same problem after an unexpected power loss.

Solutions mentioned before did not work so I compared the `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources` folder with a backup. The backup did not have the `.snap` file which was present in the current workspace. After deleting this file, Eclipse did start again.

(I first have tried the solution of Kainda, which did not work to me but did result in no open Editor tab's.)

Eclipse version: Luna Release (4.4.0)

Comment: wanted to post this answer too ;)

Answer (score 2):

A google of your error message lead to [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436467) and [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428975). Both were solved by starting on a new workspace. If you have selected to not have have workspace dialog appear on startup, use the `-data <workspace>` argument when starting eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I had to delete (rename) my .metadata/.plugins directory for eclipse to startup.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem but none of the above specified solutions worked for me.

What I did was delete the `.metadata` directory inside the `workspace` directory of the eclipse. After doing this, eclipse started like a charm but it didn't had any projects in its project explorer. I just imported all the projects at once and it was rolling once again.

Eclipse version:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20161007-1200
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. All of sudden Eclipse was not starting. Checked the .log file in eclipse configuration and had same exception with root cause

> java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.osgi.internal..framework.BundleContextImpl.close(BundleContextImpl.java:92)

In my case problem is not with workspace, followed the solution from [*eclipse forum*](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=823236&goto=1709703&#msg_1709703),

> I took the first class reporting the error, 
>      i.e. org.eclipse.osgi and deleted the (lock) files under configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager
> Files had names starting with .fileTable 
>  I was then able to start Eclipse without a computer reboot but did have to specify the workspace when it restarted.

after removing the .lock file from eclipse configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager folder, I could be able to start eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1. backup on a zip all your files from this folder
2. delete the files 
   the folder is
   \MyEclipse 2017 CI\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager

restart myeclipse