# Framework event error

Tags: java, maven

I created web maven project. For this I have used Maven integration for Eclipse(Luna)1.5.0 and JDK 1.6. When I am executing that project it generates following error:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.6.0_33
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.core.runtime
Error
Tue Aug 04 11:01:13 IST 2015
FrameworkEvent ERROR

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.core.runtime"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.0.v20140318-2214"; singleton:="true" [id=86] STARTED [STARTED]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.lockStateChange(Module.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: maybe related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598594/my-eclipse-luna-wont-start-up)